# Tesseract Handwritten Digit Fails

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I try to train tesseract with mnist dataset using jtessbox. First I am creating the images and box files like this.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQaxU.png)
In dataset there is 60.000 images of digits and I can create so many new images like the sample. After dataset creation i create box files.
After that with jTessBoxEditor in trainer tab I'm choosing **combine_tessdata.exe** as **tesseract executables** and one of new created image as **Training Data** after all done I am choosing **Train With Existing Box** and running.

(I try models on VietOcr.)

If I create 1.000 sample and their boxes the model predicts 0 or 2 like it is learned nothing

But if i create 50 sample with their boxes the model predict more accurate but still pretty bad predictions.

So my question is where am I doing wrong ?
Do i skip a step or tesseract is not able to be learn handwritten digits ?